# Redirecting parent page from Html.renderAction child without using Ajax, Java, Jquery or such

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem where I have a form in a Html.RenderAction and after submitting the form I have to reload the parent but I keep getting "Child actions can not perform redirect actions". So how can I solve it without Ajax etc.

In my parent I have:

```
  @{ 
            var UserReviewExist = Model.Reviews.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AspNetUser.UserName == Name.AspNetUser.UserName);

        }

        @{if (UserReviewExist == null)
            {

                Html.RenderAction("ReviewCreate", "Reviews", new { BookID = Model.Id });
            }
        }
```

My RenderAction View contains this:

```
    @model Trigger_Happy_Bunnies.Models.Review
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@{
    if (true)
    {
        Trigger_Happy_Bunnies.Models.Review newReview = new Trigger_Happy_Bunnies.Models.Review();
        <div style="border:1px black">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and ends with

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And lastly I have this in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ReviewCreate([Bind(Include = "Id,BookId,UserId,Text,Title,Rating,IsActive,IsReported,ReportedBy,ReportReason,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy,CreatedDate")] Review review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Reviews.Add(review);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("~/Views/Reviews/ReviewCreate.cshtml");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", review.UserId);
        ViewBag.BookId = new SelectList(db.Books, "Id", "UserId", review.BookId);
        return PartialView();
    }
```

So how can I update the parent view when submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is here. A child action merely dumps its response into the view. So at the end of the day, whether you used a child action, a partial or just plopped the code right in the view, you just have a one HTML document that includes a form.

Calling `Html.BeginForm` with no parameters says basically that it should use the current action, but even in the context of child action, that's still going to be the main action being rendered. So, your form will post to that main action, *not* your child action.

That's how it *should* be. You cannot post to a child action, because that makes no sense in the context of a web page. Technically, you *can* as long as it's not marked as `[ChildActionOnly]`, but the entire page will change to the partial view that's returned as the response, sans layout. If you want to replace just the area that was rendered via the child action, you must submit an AJAX request that returns the partial response and manually replace the appropriate node in the DOM with that.

In other words, that's why a child action can't redirect. It's not a true action and it hasn't been routed to. It's not rendered until the response preparation phase, and by that point, there's already data in the response, preventing any changes, like a redirect. If you need to redirect after the post of the form, you should have that already in place, just make sure your main action has a version that handles post, and redirect from there.

Comment: The code works to the extend that the post is saved to the database, but nothing is updated. That is all the fields stay filled in and everything. If I use return View() in the controller, the child flickers but everything remains. The main does not get updated in any way.

Comment: But thank you! You helped me understand how it works and made me move the post-responses to the correct controller. Now everything works!